# How to remove text in between \r's including \r from a text file?? And if any text contains \r in between ' ' that also should be removed

Tags: python, regex, stripping

```
'Aadhirai' 'A special star' '6' 'Boy' '' "\rgoogletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1445572280350-0'); });\r" 'Aadhiren' 'Dark' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadhish' 'King Commanded Counselled' '5' 'Boy' '' 'Aadhyatm' 'Dhyan' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadi' 'First Most important Beginning Ornament Adornment' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadia' 'Being a gift' '7' 'Boy' '' 'Aadidev' 'The first God' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadijay' 'The first victory' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadim' 'Entire universe' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadinath' 'The first Lord Lord Vishnu' '4' 'Boy' '' 'Aadipta' 'Bright' '7' 'Boy' '' 'Aadish' 'Full of wisdom Intelligent' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadishankar' 'Sri shankaracharya Founder of Adwaitha philosophy' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadit' 'Peak Lord of Sun' '8' 'Boy' '' 'Aaditey' 'Son of Aditi' '11' 'Boy' '' '\r        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || ).push({});\r    '
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting, and 2) can you post the code you've got so far?

Comment: you should show your expected output and what you have done so far

Comment: `string.replace('\r','')` ??

Comment: replacing \r wont work.. Have to delete values in between too.. Can u help me how to use code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is remove data between `\r and another \r`.The correct thing to use here would be regex.

**Code:**

```
import re
check="""'Aadhirai' 'A special star' '6' 'Boy' '' "\rgoogletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1445572280350-0'); });\r" 'Aadhiren' 'Dark' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadhish' 'King Commanded Counselled' '5' 'Boy' '' 'Aadhyatm' 'Dhyan' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadi' 'First Most important Beginning Ornament Adornment' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadia' 'Being a gift' '7' 'Boy' '' 'Aadidev' 'The first God' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadijay' 'The first victory' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadim' 'Entire universe' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadinath' 'The first Lord Lord Vishnu' '4' 'Boy' '' 'Aadipta' 'Bright' '7' 'Boy' '' 'Aadish' 'Full of wisdom Intelligent' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadishankar' 'Sri shankaracharya Founder of Adwaitha philosophy' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadit' 'Peak Lord of Sun' '8' 'Boy' '' 'Aaditey' 'Son of Aditi' '11' 'Boy' '' '\r        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || ).push({});\r    '"""
print re.sub(r"\r.*?\r"," ",check)
```

**Output:**

```
'Aadhirai' 'A special star' '6' 'Boy' '' " " 'Aadhiren' 'Dark' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadhish' 'King Commanded Counselled' '5' 'Boy' '' 'Aadhyatm' 'Dhyan' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadi' 'First Most important Beginning Ornament Adornment' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadia' 'Being a gift' '7' 'Boy' '' 'Aadidev' 'The first God' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadijay' 'The first victory' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadim' 'Entire universe' '1' 'Boy' '' 'Aadinath' 'The first Lord Lord Vishnu' '4' 'Boy' '' 'Aadipta' 'Bright' '7' 'Boy' '' 'Aadish' 'Full of wisdom Intelligent' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadishankar' 'Sri shankaracharya Founder of Adwaitha philosophy' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aadit' 'Peak Lord of Sun' '8' 'Boy' '' 'Aaditey' 'Son of Aditi' '11' 'Boy' '' '     '
```

**Notes:**

- `re` module is used for doing `regex` matches
- `\r.*?\r` is the regex I am trying to match it say to `start from \r match everything until next \r`

Comment: Its perfectly fine.. But Could you help me to remove the quotes also in which \r is present.. i.e completely remove that string including quotes

Comment: By quotes which quotes you want to remove all the quotes are `just the \r quotes`

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
"define filtering function"
good = lambda x : not( x.startswith("\r") and x.endswith() )
"use with statement with open!"
with open('/home/rohit/Desktop/output.txt', 'r') as filein:
    with open('/home/rohit/Desktop/output1.txt','w') as fileout1:
       for line in filein:
           cols = line.rstrip("\n").split(',')
           "remove unwanted columns"
           cols = list( filter( good , cols ) )
           for c in cols:
               fileout1.write(c)
```